# Pointycastle AES hat polynomial runtime? [Flutter/Dart]

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I'm using pointycastle (by BouncyCastle) in Flutter for encryption/decryption. I've got the following code for encryption:

```
Uint8List encrypt(Uint8List key, Uint8List iv, String encryptionMethod, Uint8List data) {
    if (key.isEmpty || iv.isEmpty || encryptionMethod == "" || data.isEmpty) return Uint8List(0);


    final paddedBlockCipher = PaddedBlockCipher("AES/CFB-64/PKCS7");

    //initialize paddedBlockCipher
    final parametersWithIV = ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>(KeyParameter(key), iv);
    final paddedBlockCipherParameters = PaddedBlockCipherParameters(parametersWithIV,null);
    paddedBlockCipher.init(true, paddedBlockCipherParameters);

    final result = paddedBlockCipher.process(data);

    return result;
  }
```

`PaddedBlockCipher` is part of the framework. I've noticed that if I input Uint8Lists of 200KB or more, it takes way too long. So I analysed the line
`final result = paddedBlockCipher.process(data);`
using debug mode with different data sizes and it turns out it has at least a polynomial runtime. Here is what i found:

Input Size (KB) | time (s)
200              | 2 
400              | 15
800              | 77
1600             | 330

How is that even possible? I mean "process" is just supposed to do AES on every block which should be linear shouldn't it? Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is this only for CFB or also for other modes like CBC? By the way, CFB is a stream cipher mode and should not need padding.

Comment: You're right, it's a lot better with f.e. CBC. BUt nothing more than like 2-3 MB/s. What i found online is way above 10MB/s, some even well over 100MB/s. That just seems kinda fishy to me.